# How to make some URL mappings depending on the environment?

Tags: grails, url-mapping

When getting an HTTP status code 500, I want to display 2 different pages according to the running environment.

**In development mode**, I want to display a stackStrace page (like the default Grails 500 error page) and **in production mode**, I want to display a formal "internal error" page.

Is it possible and how can I do that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do environment specific mappings within `UrlMappings.groovy`

`grails.util.GrailsUtil` to the rescue

Its not pretty, but I think it will solve your issue

E.g

```
import grails.util.GrailsUtil

class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {


        if(GrailsUtil.getEnvironment() == "development") {

             "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
                constraints {
                    // apply constraints here
                }
            }

            "/"(view:"/devIndex")
            "500"(view:'/error')
        }

        if(GrailsUtil.getEnvironment() == "test") {
            "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
                constraints {
                    // apply constraints here
                }
            }

            "/"(view:"/testIndex")
            "500"(view:'/error')

        }



        if(GrailsUtil.getEnvironment() == "production") {
            "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
                constraints {
                    // apply constraints here
                }
            }

            "/"(view:"/prodIndex")
            "500"(view:'/error')

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. I'll try it and update this thread. Is it not possible to have the if condition ONLY for "500" mapping?

Comment: Yes. The above is just an example

Comment: Or you can also check the environment directly from GSP (like <g:if env="production">) and adjust display accordingly.

Comment: You can just put this `"500"(view: environment == 'production' ? '/prodError' : '/error')` or maybe even this `"500"(view: "${environment}-error")`, both providing that `import static grails.util.GrailsUtil.environment`

Comment: As `GrailsUtil.getEnvironment()` is depreciated better to use `Environment.getCurrent()` or simply `Environment.current`. Beside I recommend using enum values like `Environment.TEST`, `Environment.PRODUCTION`, etc. on the right side of condition check.

Answer (score 14):

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but I'd got with mapping the error code to a controller and handling the logic there:

```
class UrlMappings {

   static mappings = {

      "/$controller/$action?/$id?" { constraints {} }

      "/"(view:"/index")

      "403"(controller: "errors", action: "accessDenied")
      "404"(controller: "errors", action: "notFound")
      "405"(controller: "errors", action: "notAllowed")
      "500"(view: '/error')
   }
}
```

and then create the corresponding controller (grails-app/conf/controllers/ErrorsController.groovy):

```
import grails.util.Environment

class ErrorsController extends AbstractController {

   def accessDenied = {}

   def notFound = {}

   def notAllowed = {}

   def serverError = {
      if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
         render view: '/error'
      }
      else {
         render view: '/errorProd'
      }
   }
}
```

You'll need to create the corresponding GSPs in grails-app/views/errors (accessDenied.gsp, notFound.gsp, etc.) and also the new grails-app/views/errorProd.gsp. By routing to a controller method for all error codes you make it easier to add logic to the other error code handlers in the future.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work for 405. In my case it is working for all other response codes.